# C++/Qt - Compile problem: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier - No idea

Tags: c++, qt

I have the very simple following code:

main.cpp

```
#include "ui_library_browser.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "StartWindow.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  StartWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

StartWindow.h

```
#ifndef STARTWINDOW_H_
#define STARTWINDOW_H_

#include <qwidget>
#include "MainWindow.h"

class StartWindow : public QWidget
{ 
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  StartWindow();
  ~StartWindow();
  MainWindow main_window;  //<-- Problem
};
#endif
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H_
#define MAINWINDOW_H_

#include <qdialog.h>
#include "StartWindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MainWindow();
  ~MainWindow();
};
#endif
```

I get the following errors:

moc_MainWindow.cpp

> StartWindow.h(14): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'main_window'
>   StartWindow.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   StartWindow.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

I've written a few C++/Qt apps before, but I'm bamboozled by this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have circular dependencies on your headers. Remove the `#include "StartWindow.h"` from your `MainWindow.h` file.

Comment: I thought #ifndef and #define removes this problem?

Comment: @johnnyturn No, if you include MainWindow.h, it includes StartWindow.h before declaring MainWindow, which then uses MainWindow before it is declared. Think of the preprocessor as copy-n-pasting header contents for each #include into one single source file which is then compiled.